# Log output from scripts running in separate processes

Tags: linux, shell, logging, sh

I'm copying several sql tables between different databases. For each table there is prepared separate script with `DROP..CREATE..AS SELECT..` operations plus some `PROMPT..` and `SELECT SYSDATE..` operations for log purposes. All output informations (`Table dropped, Table created, etc.`) have to be collected in one file.

I've tried that code:

```
sqlplus -S user/password/sid @CopyScript1.sql > Output.log &
sqlplus -S user/password/sid @CopyScript2.sql > Output.log &
sqlplus -S user/password/sid @CopyScript3.sql > Output.log &
wait
```

Tables are copied as I wanted, but log file is complete mess:

```
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
TABLE1 table creation b
Tabl
Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:0
Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.43

03-06-2013 19:18:45

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
TABLE2 table creation end
end
n end
```

What should I change to get proper log?

---

EDIT:
Each log entry can consist of several lines (SYSDATE and 1+ lines of comments, plus eventually timing of finished operation, f.ex.:

```
(00:00:14)
2013-06-04 02:08
Provided example of log entry
can consist of more than 1 line
```

Log entries in result file should be sorted by entry date.

Answer (score 0):

Log each query to a different file, then use "cat *.log" to put them back together.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated question. Simple concatenation won't work in my case as log entries have to be sorted. `cat *.log | sort > Output.log` will not work either, as entries are multiline and only one of lines is with date (but we can assume that date to sort is alwaus in 2nd line of entry and entries are separated by empty line).

Comment: In that case, you'll have to write something custom in perl/sed/whatever. It's highly dependent on the exact format of your file.